# Is it possible that each finite sum is a perfect power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

*Rough question:* Does there exist an infinite set of positive integers such that the sum of any finite subset is a perfect power?

Comment: It is implied by [this generalization of Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Generalization): pick one element $a$ and consider the pairs of numbers $(b,b+a)$, $(c,c+a)$ etc. all of which must be perfect powers.

Comment: I don't get your solution sorry: this is not an open question..