# Constellations of three powers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I prove that for all $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ there are only a finite number of solutions to $x^a + i + j = y^b + j = z^c$ with $a,b,c,x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b,c \ge 2$?  This is a weaker version of [this generalization of Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Generalization) which would give a negative answer to [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477253/is-it-possible-that-each-finite-sum-is-a-perfect-power).

I can see that the set of solutions has at most a certain density.  I'm interested in learning new tools for solving this problem and also the linked question.